# Order of nofityAll in producer-consumer pattern

Tags: java, parallel-processing

I have an example of an producer-consumer pattern, where `notifyAll` is placed before `queue.remove()`. Is this important or just because of convenience?

```
synchronized void post(Work w) {
    while (queue.isFull()) this.wait();
    queue.add(w);
    this.notifyAll();
}

synchronized Work get() {
    while (queue.isEmpty()) this.wait();
    // is the order at this point important, or could I switch this part?
    this.notifyAll();
    return queue.remove();
}
```

Comment: Why should you wait/notify on this rather than queue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could switch them around and still get the same behaviour. It's done this way, because otherwise you'll need an additional local variable and line of code to hold the element you removed from the queue. Not that it matters (it does **not** affect performance), but why wouldn't you write the code in the simplest way possible.

```
Work w = queue.remove();  // Unnecessary
this.notifyAll();
return w;
```